# Localise @Html.EditorFor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

In my asp .net mvc4 application I need to implement to support "English" and "Arabic". Within the Global.asac.cs I'm setting the culture like this. "ar" is hardcoded to showing purpose in here. I'm using a cookie to selected language.

```
protected void Application_PreRequestHandlerExecute()
        {
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("ar");
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("ar");
        }
```

For the arabic language each pages Html controls like Editors, not showing the arabic letters when user typing. How can I solve this by language changes.

Comment: [Check this link](http://geekswithblogs.net/shaunxu/archive/2010/05/06/localization-in-asp.net-mvc-ndash-3-days-investigation-1-day.aspx). This may help.

Answer (score 0):

you can capture the keydown event and replace the character with something like this:

```
$('textarea').on('keydown', function(e){

   console.log(e.keyCode); 
    if( e.keyCode == 90 ){
      e.preventDefault();
      $(this).append('y').focus();
    }
    if( e.keyCode == 89 ){
      e.preventDefault();
      $(this).append('z').focus();
    }

});​
```